# Cannot Trigger WakefulBroadcastReciever

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

So I am doing this project where at a determined time the cellphone would automatically be put on silent mode (no sound), and someone here suggested me to use WakefulBroadcastReciever. I tried to look for some old topics here on how it works and tried to implement it on my code, but no matter what I do, it does not start on the determined time. Can someone help me? Here is the code, where hourStart and minuteStart are determined by the user previously:

```
public void alarm(){

    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourStart);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteStart);
    Log.d("calendartimeValue", String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SoundWakefulReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("SOUND_ACTION");

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
}



public class SoundWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, SoundService.class);
    Log.d("receiver", "receiver here !!");
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}
}



public class SoundService extends IntentService {

public SoundService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    AudioManager amanager;
    Log.d("service","service started!!");
    amanager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
    SoundWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
}
```

p.s: I already declared the "SOUND_ACTION" on the manifest and enabled the user-permission to modify the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `WAKE_LOCK` permission in your manifest in order to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. I am kinda new in Android programming. However, it is still not working even with the permission =/. If I change the WakefulBroadcast to just a Broadcast and send a broadcast on the alarm() function it works fine, but in that way I cannot predetermine a time to send the broadcast.

Comment: It seems a bit weird that you use PendingIntent.getService but supply an intent intended for a receiver. When the alarm is fired, the system will call startService with your receiver intent. I reckon you want PendingIntent.getBroadcast?

Comment: Yah, you're right. I was using getBroadcast before, but as it was not working I tried to change it to getService just to see if it would work that way, but then I changed it back to getBroadcast with the modifications in the permission and it still did not work.

Comment: I also tried to change the hourStart and minuteStart to fixed values just in case it was some problem with the number that I was getting, but as I suspected, it was not the case.